# What does the square-zero ideal means

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, ideals

I tried to study why Krull's intersection theorem won't work in non-Noetherian rings. It was said [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71699/counter-examples-to-krulls-intersection-theorem) that the example written by *user2035* works by taking some kind of square-zero ideal. How do one defines a square-zero ideal of a ring? Is it just an ideal $I$ such that $I^2=0$?

Answer (score 2):

We say that an ideal is a **square zero ideal** if $I^2=0$.

For example, let $I=(x) \subset k[x]/(x^2)$. Then $I^2=0$.