# A unital commutative ring having a square-zero maximal ideal is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

I have the following question in my homework.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ be a maximal ideal of $R$ such that $M^2=\{0\}$. Show that $M$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$.

### My attempt:

I see that it's trivially true if $M=\{0\}$ in which case, $R$ becomes a field. However, in general,

$M^2=\{0\}\implies m_1m_2=0 \  \forall \ m_1,m_2\in M$.

This means all elements of $M$ are zero-divisors (and nilpotent too).

What are other implications of $M$ being an ideal which is both [square-zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1149255/955582) and maximal?

I am not sure how to proceed. I am doing an introductory ring theory course so do not use advanced theorems/tools to guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption every element of $M$ is nilpotent and [hence](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Nilradical_equals_intersection_of_all_prime_ideals)* is contained in every prime ideal of $R$. This immediately implies that $M$ is equal to every prime ideal, and we see that $R$ has exactly one prime ideal (which, by the way, is much stronger than having exactly one maximal ideal).

*Here we only need the trivial observation that every prime ideal contains every nilpotent element ($x^n = 0 \in P \implies x \in P$).

Comment: $M\subseteq N(R)\implies M\subseteq P$ for any prime ideal $P$ of $R$. By maximality of $M$, we get $M=P$. Thus, $M$ is the only prime ideal of $R$. Now we use that fact that in a commutative ring with identity, every maximal ideal is a prime ideal to conclude the proof statement. Amazing..! I am getting so many different approaches to the same problem, it's worth asking questions here...

Comment: Yes. It's just that simple.

Answer (score 4):

Let $N$ be a maximal ideal. We prove that $M=N$. Since $N$ is maximal in a ring with unity, [$N$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146752/742).  (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169251/742))

Since $MM=M^2=\{0\}\subseteq N$, the primality of $N$ yields $M\subseteq N$. Since $M$ is maximal and $N\neq R$, we conclude that $M=N$.

(Note that this also works for noncommutative rings with unity, and more generally noncommutative rings with $R^2$ not contained in any maximal ideal)

Comment: How does primality of $N$ yield $M\subseteq N$?

Comment: Do you mean that primality works as subsets too? I didn't know that. If $AB\subseteq N$ then $A\subseteq N$ or $B\subseteq N$. Is that true? How do I prove it? The definition of primality I know is that if $ab\in N$ then $a\in N$ or $b\in N$.

Comment: @Nothingspecial The general definition of prime ideal is "$P$ is a prime deal iff it is an ideal, $P\neq R$, and for any **ideals** $A$ and $B$, if $AB\subseteq P$, then either $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$." This is equivalent to the elementwise definition for commutative rings, but it is weaker (and the *correct* notion) for non-commutative rings. It is easy that the elementwise version implies this one. For the converse in the commutative setting, use principal ideals. Follow the link I gave for some discussion.

Comment: @Nothingspecial The product of $M$ with $M$ is contained in $N$, with $M$ an ideal, so either $M$ is contained in $N$ or $M$ is contained in $N$. i.e., $M$ is contained in $N$, using the definition of "prime ideal".

Comment: I see that it's more general and sometimes more useful definition... If I knew this definition, this problem would have been trivial... :) But my course, being an introductory one, focuses mostly on commutative rings with identity.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\notin M$, then exists $r\in R, m\in M$ s.t.
$$rx+m=1.$$
Then $$0=m^2=(1-rx)^2=1-2rx+r^2x^2. $$
i.e, $1=x(2r-r^2x)$. Therefore $x$ is invertible. Every element in $R-M$ is invertible $\implies $ $M$ is the unique maximal ideal.

Comment: If I understood correctly, $Rx+M=R$ because $M$ is maximal. Thus, $1\in Rx+M$. But I am not sure why the last implication is true. What does all elements of $R\setminus M$ are invertible imply that $M$ is the unique maximal ideal?

Comment: Oh I got it, after some thought! If $N$ is another maximal ideal, it must contain one of those invertible elements (say, $x$) which is not in $M$. Thus, $Rx$ is contained in $N$. Now, $1\in Rx\subseteq N$. Hence, $N=R$ (contradiction)

Comment: Assume $R$ has another maximal ideal $M_0\ne M$. Since $M_0$ is maximal, it can not be contained strictly in $M$, and $M_0\ne M$ by hypothesis. Therefore $M_0$ is not a subset of $M$, i.e. $M_0-M\ne\varnothing$. But if $a\in M_0-M$, then $a$ must be invertible since $a\in R-M$, implying $M_0=R$, which is absurd. Generally speaking,  if an ideal consists of all of the non-invertible elements, then it is the unique maximal ideal.

Comment: @Nothingspecial Nice observation! You figured it out before I finish typing. But I still recommend you read my proof because it is more detailed, and you can check if you understood correctly.

Comment: Your general result will help me later... If all zero divisors of $R$ are contained in an ideal $I\neq R$ then $I$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: Well, I am a little doubtful on whether this is correct. What if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=\{0\}$?

Comment: But zero divisor, by the definition I am used to, is a **non-zero element** which "divides" $0$.

Comment: Well, the set of zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\varnothing$ and is therefore contained in $\{0\}$. Maybe it is true if $R$ has non-zero zero divisors? Let me think of the question.

Comment: @Nothingspecial  Ok, I think I have come up with a counterexample. Take $R=\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, the polynomial ring on $\mathbb{Z}_4$. Then the zero divisors (including $0$) is the ideal generated by $\bar{2}$.  But $\langle\bar{2}\rangle$ is not maximal since it is strictly contained in $\langle\bar{2}, x\rangle$. The latter does not equal $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$.